# Воспроизведение <audio> при клике на блок с одновременной остановкой текущего

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блоки с содержащихся в них  файлами
Необходимо, чтобы по клику на блоке с классом "play" воспроизведение других аудио прекращалось, а аудио, содержащееся в блоке, по которому кликнули, воспроизводилось либо ставилось на паузу через jQuery

```
<div class="play">
 <img src="img/icons/play.png">
 <audio src="media/music/Robbie Williams - Feel.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

пытаюсь сделать так

```
$('.play').click(function() {
  audioElement.pause();
  $(this).find('audio').trigger("play");
});
```

если убрать

```
audioElement.pause();
```

то аудио воспроизводится, но другое не прерывается

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: Если требуется избегать одновременного воспроизведения, не проще будет на странице использовать только один элемент аудио, и задавать ему разные src?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что такое `audioElement`?

```
$('.play').click(function() {
  $('audio').not($(this).find('audio')).trigger("pause");
  $(this).find('audio').trigger("play");
});
```

Comment: Благодарю. А что можно в $('audio').not($(this).find('audio')).trigger("pause"); добавить, что бы не пауза была, а сбрасывалась на начало, и при повторном клике заново начиналось?

Comment: @Артем Пожалуйста. Давайте так. Вы примите этот ответ - "галочка" слева - и задайте новый вопрос.